# How to make composed class names styles with SASS and CSS modules

Tags: css, sass, next.js, css-selectors, css-modules

I have a Next.js project and I'm studying using SCSS/SASS for styling. I'm trying to figure out the best way to simplify the class name styling.

So right now I'm having the following problem:

I have a component like:

```
import styles from './component.module.scss';

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className='content'>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to make a simple .scss like:

```
.container {
  background-color: red;

  .content {
    background-color: blue;
  }


}
```

The class `.container` works well. But to be able to apply `.content` I would have to change the 2nd div's classname to `{styles.content}` instead of just `content`.

Is there a way to use `styles.CLASS` only in the top div of the component and not have to use it for every children's div?

Comment: If you want to apply the styles coming from your SASS module file then you have to use `styles.<class-name>` syntax. Using `className='content'` will simply point to a global class name `.content` (not the one from the SASS module file).

Answer (score 1):

You can Add a Global Stylesheet to app.js, and use it like that everywhere:

```
<div className='content'> ... </div>
```

or a module Stylesheet, and use it like that, only in files you imported it

```
import styles from './component.module.scss';

    <div className={styles.container}> ... </div>
```

if you want it like that:

```
 <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className='content'>
        ...
      </div>
 </div>
```

you need to create 2 Stylesheets

1. a module Stylesheet and import it to a specific file
2. a global Stylesheet and import it to app.js